# How to assign multiple Targets to a AWS Loadbalancer TargetGroup Target in a single line?

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml, aws-cloudformation

How can I pass a parameter (of type CommaDelimitedList or String) to a single TargetGroup's Target: -Id: property and have it iterate through and assign each instance in the list?

Currently right now I am able to pass one or more Target-Servers to a Target-Group by having each Target as it's own -Id: property. Code block #1 below works, how can I make code block #2 work?

```
    MyTargetGroup:
        Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::TargetGroup
            Properties: 
             #[All the Target Group properties that aren't in question]
              Targets: 
                - Id: "i-000AWS001"
                Or 
                - Id: !Ref WebServer1
```

```
#Two Files:
#   resource.yml  -  Cloudformation yaml file
#   conf_resource.json  -  json paramaters file

# Parameter value in the Conf file
{
    "WebServers":"i-000AWS001,i-000AWS002,i-000AWS003,i-000AWS004,i-000AWS005"
}
# ..

#Target Group Resource
Parameters:
    WebServers:
        Type: CommaDelimitedList
        Default: "@@@WebServers@@@"
        Description: " A comma delimited list of AWS Ec2 Webserver instances"

Resources:
    MyAlb:
        ALBProperties:
            #[All the Application Load balancer properties that aren't in question]
        
    MyTargetGroup:
        Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::TargetGroup
            Properties: 
             #[All the Target Group properties that aren't in question]
              Targets: 
                - Id: !Split[ "," , !Ref WebServers ]
    #Also tried - Id: !Ref [ !Split[ "," , !Ref WebServers ] ]
```

AWS TargetGroup Documentation:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-elasticloadbalancingv2-targetgroup.html#cfn-elasticloadbalancingv2-targetgroup-targets

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You **can't do this**, such list operations are not supported in CloudFormation.

But, normally what you do is to place your instances in **AutoScaling Group**. This way, the group will be automatically registering instances with your balancer, and you don't have to worry about individual instance ids.

Comment: I figured it might not be possible but wanted to try, I'll look in to Autoscaling for a future solution.  Thanks so much for your reply!

Comment: @JosephBourgoin No problem. ASG should the the way to go. ASG+LB work nicely together.